# Changed the Url of my Magento 2 and now getting cgi-sys errors

Tags: magento2

I have changed the `URL` of my **Magento** in **admin panel**.

After **DNS** updated, I'm trying to access the domain but I get following CPanel error page:

> http://www.xxxxxxx.co.il/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

I doubled checked the `core_config_data` to make sure domain is changed and it is.

**I have cleared cache, ran reindex, content deploy** but
still same result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: it should take some time to reflect after updated the DNS! So can you please try again after some times?